# SQL : Insert Or Update command

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using "Voila Norbert" API and I would like to store results in a DB table like this :

```
email_Norbert (
id    Integer(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
idUser    Integer(11) NOT NULL,
email     VarChar(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
score     Integer(2),
existence TinyInt(1),
PRIMARY KEY (
        id
)
```

Actually I use this query (as an example, I set values but it changes everytime for each idUser) :

```
INSERT INTO email_Norbert (idUser,email,score) 
VALUES (2 ,'MyEmailHere',100) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE idUser = 2,email = 'MyEmailHere', score = 100
```

The insert run well but when the record already exist, I does add an other record.

What should I do ?

Comment: I didn't know I was famous...

Comment: Haha :D. Any ideas ?

Comment: Not sure if I understood but if You expected the insert to fail, then you should set primary key to include idUser also

Comment: do you need the duplicate key syntax. the only key you have is the increment column which isnt in your insert statement, so i doubt it would ever fire! Either that or if you want the insert to fail put a unique index on the iduser field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want subsequent inserts for same user to fail and instead update, add a unique index on the iduser column.

```
create unique index email_Norbert_u1 on email_Norbert(iduser)
```

Comment: Working ! Thank you so much :D

Comment: I was just 3 seconds late I also got the solution :P but for more clarification i want to say that at least one column must be unique for the update operation.